# Magento 2.3 error after filling in credit card info

Tags: payment-gateway, magento2.3

We are using the **payunity extension** and following payment methods are available to our customer: **Check/money, Visa, MasterCard and Sofortuberweisung**.

The **extension** is set to **test mode**. If I set **Payment Authorization** to **Server Authorization** instead of **Widget Authorization** I can finish an order with **Sofortuberweisung payment method** without an error. But the credit card payment methods have only Widget Authorization available. The check/money payment method works fine.

I can get through the checkout without an issue but after I place the order it redirects me to this url: **`/payunitycw/checkout/widget/`** where the widget in which I have to enter the credit card info is.

After I fill in the test credit card info and submit, I get this error:

> {"result":{"code":"200.300.404","description":"invalid or missing parameter","parameterErrors":[{"name":"form_key","value":"w3R1CsKRddwqheI2","message":"is not an allowed parameter"}]},"buildNumber":"deebd8c9af7d84ddee98c38b7f4afcc814012b5b@2019-01-22 13:58:00 +0000","timestamp":"2019-01-25 08:36:29+0000","ndc":"C54C9C1378FE55CE7A8407823A07DD5F.uat01-vm-tx02"}

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: so it was an issue in payunity extension and we solved it by installing the new version of pauynity extension